# Unable to use Evolution for GMail, Hotmail, Zimbra on Ubuntu

Tags: proxy, email, evolution, gmail, zimbra

I have correctly configured all the email accounts with IMAP settings. I believe it is due to the network proxy of my institute that is causing the hindrance. I have put proxy settings in the network settings of Evolution as well. No luck so far. Pls see if you can help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you access your Gmail from the browser? May it be that you have a company policy that blocks E-Mail (we have because of viruses)?

Comment: @Takkat Oh no, web works fine. In fact, I need a client so that I don't have to open a web page again and again!